# Electric potential and electric potential energy

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

I have a simple question about the electric potential and electric potential energy.

The gradient of the electric potential gives us the electric field,
and the gradient of the electric potential energy gives us the force.

Am I correct in my statements or no?

Answer (score 1):

Electric potential is a scalar field: it has a value at every point in space, and its negative gradient is the electric field. Electrostatic (potential) energy is different: it is just a single value associated with a configuration of charges, in this sense it has no "gradient".

However, there are ways you can make the energy into a scalar field. You can take a charged object, place it at position $\vec{r}$, and call the energy of the resulting configuration $W(\vec{r})$. We can then speak of the gradient of $W(\vec{r})$. The force on this charged object is the negative gradient of $W(\vec{r})$, *provided no energy is supplied to the system* (e.g. by a battery) *except by the force moving the charged object*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are entirely correct.